# Using MSBuild.exe To Build A Simple Windows Phone 7 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, msbuild

I have a clean, Windows 7 x64 box setup to build and run Windows Phone 7 projects. I installed *Windows Phone Developer Tools 7.0*, *January 2011 Update* and *Windows Phone Developer Tools Fix* as per the [MSDN App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/en-us/home/getting_started) page. My WP7 applications build fine in VisualStudio, yet when I try to use MSBuild.exe, even on the simplest Visual Studio project

> c:\Windows\Microsfot.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe .\SimpleWP7.sln

I get the following errors (with added space between lines for readability)

> ... verbose.output ...
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight
>   for
>   Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(185,9):
>   error MSB4018: The "CompileXaml" task
>   failed unexpectedly.\r
>   [C:\Users\alasdair.mccall\vs_workspace\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight
>   for
>   Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(185,9):
>   error MSB4018:
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not
>   load file or assembly
>   'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or
>   one of its dependencies. The given
>   assembly name or codebase was invalid.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)\r
>   [C:\Users\alasdair.mccall\vs_workspace\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7.csproj]
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\Silverlight
>   for
>   Phone\v4.0\Microsoft.Silverlight.Common.targets(185,9):
>   error MSB4018: File name:
>   'PresentationCore, Version=3.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'\r
>   [C:\Users\alasdair.mccall\vs_workspace\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7\SimpleWP7.csproj]
>
> ...

What am I missing here? I have Silverlight 3 and 4 installed and I've installed everything as documented on the App Hub. Please let me know if there is any additional information required.

Cheers,
Alasdair.

Comment: See second post: http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/75679/460407.aspx#460407 Make sure you're using VS CMD prompt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using the wrong msbuild executable, I should have been using

```
c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe
```

I'm unsure why, on Windows 7 64bit I should've been using what appears to be msbuild for 32bit applications. Thanks to @keyboardP for directing me to Visual Studio command prompt which helped diagnose this.